# Why does this spec of my model's uniqueness validation fail when it should pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I am learning testing with RSpec. Something is not working with my tests.

My model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  # Validation macros
  validates_presence_of :name, :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, case_sensitive: false
end
```

My factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name "Joe Doe"
    email "joe@example.com"
    password_digest "super_secret_password"
  end
end
```

And my spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)

  it 'has a valid factory' do
    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:user)).to be_valid
  end

  it { is_expected.to respond_to(:name) }
  it { is_expected.to respond_to(:email) }
  it { is_expected.to respond_to(:password) }
  it { is_expected.to respond_to(:password_confirmation) }

  it { expect(user).to validate_presence_of(:name) }
  it { expect(user).to validate_presence_of(:email) }
  it { expect(user).to validate_presence_of(:password) }
  it { expect(user).to validate_uniqueness_of(:email).case_insensitive }
end
```

I expected this test to pass. But I get this as a result:

> Failures:
>
> 1) User should validate that :email is case-insensitively unique
>        Failure/Error: it { expect(user).to validate_uniqueness_of(:email).case_insensitive }
>
> ```
>    User did not properly validate that :email is case-insensitively unique.
>      The record you provided could not be created, as it failed with the
>      following validation errors:
>
>      * name: ["can't be blank"]
>  # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```
>
> Finished in 0.34066 seconds (files took 1.56 seconds to load) 9
>   examples, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:18 # User should validate that :email
>   is case-insensitively unique

What I am missing?

## Update

I think that this is a bug: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/830

Comment: Are you clearing the database between tests?

Comment: @CodeGnome, yes...  I am

Comment: @CodeGnome I tried to disable the script that cleans the database, but the error still the same

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are declaring it 2 times IMO! First building user then building same user inside `expect()`.

Just use ur first user that you have built with factory-bot like so:

```
it 'has a valid factory' do
    expect(user).to be_valid
end
```

P.S
It is better to use Faker gem instead of using harcoded instances like you did in `factory.rb`

Answer (score 0):

### Your Variable Is Currently Only Set Once for All Tests

When you write code like:

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
end
```

you aren't building a new user each time you run a new spec. Likewise, using #let is the wrong approach, because [it memoizes the variable](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) even between tests. Instead, you need a to use an RSpec [before#each](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks#define-before(:each)-block) block. For example:

```
describe User do
  before do
    @user = FactoryGirl.build :user
  end

  # some specs
end
```

If you have tests which are persisting you user to the database, and if you have disabled rollback or database cleaning between tests, then your defined factory (as currently written) will certainly fail the uniqueness validation. In such cases, you may want to try:

- `User.delete_all` in your test, or otherwise cleaning your database between tests.
- Using [FactoryGirl sequences](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences) or the [Faker gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/faker) to ensure that user attributes are actually unique.

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested but the error is the same. I think it is a bug: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/830

Answer (score 0):

[USE let](http://betterspecs.org/#let)

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

  # other what you need
```

Comment: I just did that... but the error still there. I think it is a bug: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/830